# Django admin interface and added tables

Tags: database, django, sqlite

I'm using Django with sqlite to make a web app and ran into a little issue.

I created a table under `models` file called `deletedOrder`, gave it variables etc., and then ran `manage.py syncdb`. This created the table in my database and I was able to add data to the database table and read the data back out, however this added table is not showing up on the Django admin interface.

Is there something else that I have to do to get this to be in the admin page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register your models to make them show up in the admin as documented [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects).